# Can't fully reset activeElement (focus for the Tab key) to its default position

Tags: javascript, html, position, focus, accessibility

OK, I'm trying to reset the **activeElement**  from the middle of the page so that the tab key would start from the top like, the same way as the page is just refreshed.

For that purpose (tested in FF and Chrome) I'm trying to use `document.activeElement.blur()`  (from the browser console). As result, the selection of the `<a href></a>` gets visually removed (nice).
Also,running
`document.activeElement` after running `document.activeElement.blur()`
from console shows

```html
<body class="ng-tns-0-0">
```

which looks good (the `activeElement` is `body` now?)

However, if I close the console and hit the Tab key, the focus appears on the next to the previous a href - **Not to the link that is focused on page load + Tab key**.

Why and how to fix that behavior?

The question appeared from the accessibility point of view, as the significant part of the page gets rendered with another content. The tab key needed to start over, like for a new page.

Comment: Can't you select the desired element and `focus()` it, after running `document.activeElement.blur()`?

Comment: @biberman, unfortunately no. Even on this page, if you appear by hitting several Tabs on some link, then you open browser Console, then execute document.activeElement.blur();
and
document.activeElement.focus();
from Console, then close the console and hit the Tab key, you won't appear on the SO logo on the top of the page, but will appear on the next link, like you didn't execute blur() and focus() from the Console.

Comment: I think there is a difference between typing the command in the console and running the command in the program. If you type in the console the focus is out of the website...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you shouldn't use `blur()` ever, and this method shouldn't even exist.

- After having called `blur()`, you have no control of where the focus goes. It may go in menu bar, toolbars, or even go totally outside of the browser and/or become completely unrecoverable without a mouse.
- The behavior you observe with firefox and chrome isn't standard, isn't specified anywhere, may depend on OS and/or browser settings, and you don't have control at all on it

The safest solution if you want to go back to the first element of the page is probably to **focus that first element**, rather than calling `blur()` and hope for the best.

In order for any application or website to be keyboard accessible, the focus must always be under control, i.e. you must always know exactly where it is. As the method `blur()` doesn't specify where the focus goes next, you lose control of the focus when using it; so you should never use it. As far as I know, it has probably no legitimate use.